# Please pin the [ask] "How to Ask" tutorial to the top of the help page

Tags: feature-request

Often we get new users that ask questions without sufficient research.

I would like for the [How to ask](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) page to be pinned as the first item (or at least a visible item) under the Asking section of the [Help Center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help).

[image]